# How to reflect the changes done in source code in apache superset?

Tags: apache-superset

I have been making lots of changes in appearance source code (variables.less => static/assets/variables.less) of superset and then did a `superset init` but nothing changed. Do we have to do something else to reconfigure those changes?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Superset init` creates default roles and permissions, so it's a backend task! When you want to customize superset you should run backend and frontend separately as per [official instructions](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#setup-local-environment-for-development).

Then in a terminal you should have a tab for the backend, and another for the frontend. When changing the frontend's code you'll have to run `npm install` inside the superset-frontend directory once, and to run it you will have to run the command `npm run dev-server`.

All these steps are documented in the link I provided though. I recommend re-reading the documentation.

Comment: I want to deploy it to `production` server. npm run dev-server won't let me reach it from other systems.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to rebuild the assets:

`cd` into the `/assets` directory; then

```
  $ npm install
  $ npm install webpack
  $ npm run prod
```

If this doesn't work, try https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#frontend-assets

Comment: Thanks it worked. Getting an error which says: 
$ npm run prod

> superset@0.36.0 prod 

Insufficient number of arguments or no entry found.
Alternatively, run 'webpack(-cli) --help' for usage info.

Comment: Hi Shivam - my link was incorrect. You should go through the steps on https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#frontend-assets